# PySpark: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: hive, pyspark, hbase

I have a PySpark code which develops the query and runs insert into command on another Hive table which is internally mapped to a HBase table.
When I run the insert into command onto the Hive table using spark sql I get the following exception..

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HiveHBaseTableOutputFormat cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveOutputFormat
```

I checked the datatypes and tblproperties but unable to get through this exception.

The versions I am using are:

```
PySpark -- 1.6.0
Hive -- 1.1.0-cdh5.8.2
```

The table properties are:

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe'
stored by 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
with serdeproperties("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,colf:a")
tblproperties("hbase.table.name"="abc",'hbase.mapred.output.outputtable' = 'abc');
```

I tried removing the Row Format Serde even though getting the same issue..

Am I getting the issue because of the versions not getting matched?? or am I going wrong??

Comment: Waiting for this: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/18127 to come up and resolve it !

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug of spark, see this apache spark pull, https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17989